# Check constraint using datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, constraints, check-constraints

new to SQL

I'm having an issue where I am trying to implement a constraint that checks two date fields in my table. The constraint should ensure that the date difference is greater than 7 days and less than 3 months.

This is what I tried, but it didn't seem to work.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SA_Rental]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[CHK_RentalDuration] CHECK  ((datediff(day,[DateRenting],            
[DateReturning])>(7)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SA_Rental]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     
[CHK_RentalDuration1] CHECK  ((datediff(month,[DateRenting], 
[DateReturning])<(3)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SA_Rental] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_RentalDuration]
GO
```

Any ideas on where I went wrong, or any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the above `ALTER TABLE` statements generate errors, or did they just not work?

Comment: Yes they executed fine, the ones I manually ran a query for were the two check add constraints. The 3rd one was auto generated on the server

Comment: Can you also include some sample data which is not being caught by the check constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replies. After looking through it carefully, I realised it was working but just wasn't doing what I wanted it to do, so I thought it weren't working. I just basically changed it from rather than '<7' to '<=7' and the same for the months.

Thanks for your replies anyways guys, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one check with the two date restrictions:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SA_Rental] WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_RentalDuration]
CHECK (DATEDIFF(day, [DateRenting], [DateReturning]) > 7 AND
       DATEDIFF(month, [DateRenting], [DateReturning]) < 3);
```